# How do I override Docusaurus styling?

Tags: css, docusaurus

I'm implementing Docusaurus into a pre-existing webapp for user documentation. It works perfectly for what I'm trying to accomplish, but I want to change some of the baked-in styling across the app, which, I believe, comes from the package itself, making it a pain to go in and edit. This is to make things easier for me but mainly to accomplish one task:

- I want to disable the header, either using `display:none` or `height:0`, since it's unnecessary for what I'm trying to do and doesn't fit with the rest of the site's formatting.

Let me know if there's any way to override Docusaurus's styling and/or there's a way to disable the header. Janky solutions and hacks are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posted this question without looking hard enough thru the Docusaurus docs;

My solution was to use `docusaurus swizzle` which allows you to pull in parts of the theme to override yourself. Was able to restyle the heading that way.